# What parameter should be changed in SGBM algorithm to invert depth value in depth image

Tags: opencv, kinect, depth, vision

The depth image that we get from the SGBM algorithm plots the nearest depth with white (255) and farthest value with black (0). I want that to be in reverse, the far value need to be in white (255) and near value in black (0). To alter this output in SGBM, please suggest where and what parameter I should change in the code.

Comment: Do you mind sharing your latest code?

Comment: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/calib3d/src/stereosgbm.cpp

Comment: `depth_image = 255 - depth_image`?

Comment: Hello beaker i am changing the depth image to point cloud in my application.so for each image there will be different depth out value and and if i minus with the value 255 the point cloud wat i am getting is not a proper one what i get it without inverting.

Comment: The SGBM algorithm creates a disparity map, not a depth image. To get a depth image (or rather a 3D point cloud), you need to use [cv::reprojectImageTo3D](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga1bc1152bd57d63bc524204f21fde6e02)